# Accessing Tomcat Monitors using Java code

Tags: java, jmx

I am very new to JMX. I am trying to log the tomcat statistics like threads used, cache, sessions and other standard values. I am trying to achieve this with java code.

I have done the following things as of now. (I am trying to access the values of a local tomcat 6.0 monitor on windows)

1)I have added the following options in the catalina.bat
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

After that I restarted the tomcat server.

2) Then I wrote the following code.

```
package com.ss.fg;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

public class SystemConfigManagement
{
    static MBeanServer connection = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        getActiveSession();    
    }  
    public static void getActiveSession()throws Exception
    {
        ObjectName name=new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,path=/MMDisplay,host=localhost");
        String attrValue = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getAttribute(name, "activeSessions").toString();
        System.out.println(attrValue);

    }
}
```

I even tried context instead of path.

I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Manager,path=/MMDisplay,host=localhost
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.softsmith.floodgates.SystemConfigManagement.getActiveSession(SystemConfigManagement.java:15)
    at com.softsmith.floodgates.SystemConfigManagement.main(SystemConfigManagement.java:10)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Should I add Some jar files, or should I do some other settings..

Please help

Comment: I have error like this : Exception in thread "main" javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Manager,path=/,host=localhost

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
 MBeanServer connection = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
```

you are actually connectiong to the MBean-Server of the JVM running your program, not to that of your tomcat-instance, so it doesn't know of the Catalina-MBeans.

To establish a connection to a remote jvm try something like:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://servername:9999/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
connector.connect();
MBeanServerConnection server = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
//do work here
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,path=/manager,host=localhost");
String attrValue = mb.getAttribute(name, "activeSessions").toString();
System.out.println(attrValue);
//..and don't forget to close the connection
connector.close();
```

If the error is still there make sure you are using the correct object-name.

Comment: ok thanks , but with your code i can't connect (remote) to jmx : JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.40.20(tomcat server IP):9090(tomcat port)/jmxrmi");

Comment: : this is my error : 
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is....

I added the following options in the VM Argument in eclipse  : 

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

Comment: When your `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099` you should use this port in your JMX-connection-String.

Comment: ok I changed my code and this is new code :  

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.40.70(tomcat server ip)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090(tomcat server port)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

and now my JMXServiceURL is : "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.40.70:9090/jmxrmi"

Comment: but i have error again : Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.40.70; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

Comment: What port in tomcat is used for what type of connection? Threre's one that handles http-requests and one for the jmx-stuff - and they must not be the same!

Comment: tomcat port for http-requests  is : 9090 And
for the JMX is : 1099 .

I added : com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 
and it is my JMXServiceURL : 
"service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.40.70:1099/jmxrmi"

Comment: i have this error again : 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.40.70; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

Answer (score 1):

When i using

```
 MBeanServer connection = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
```

i am actually connectiong to the MBean-Server of the JVM running my program, not to that of my tomcat-instance, so it doesn't know of the Catalina-MBeans.
so i try to connected remotly to jmx but have error like this :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is....
```

and now i solve :

for first i added `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` to `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` directory of Tomcat and then configure the listener on `server.xml` i added the following 
snippet under the  tag :

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="10001" rmiServerPortPlatform="10002" useLocalPorts="true" />
```

and finally i set the following sentence in my catalina.bat :

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```